# Get the latest time between two timestamp with time zone

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

In psql, I want to get the latest time in each row for two columns time1 and time2 and create a new column with latest time selected from time1 and time2.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0):

That would be something like

```
SELECT greatest(time1, time2) AS newcol
FROM ...
```